# Can a Menu Bar Application switch between a popover or a menu?

Tags: swift, menu, popover, menubar, right-click

I am writing a MacOS Menu Bar Application which uses a `popover`. I have relied on a number of tutorials to get things going. The application doesn’t use a storyboard or Interface Builder.

The plan is to present a menu on right-click or a popover on left-click.

Very briefly, the code looks something like this:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover=NSPopover() 
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        //  Popover & Content View
            let contentView = ContentView()
            self.popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)

        //  Menu
            self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 18)
            if let statusBarButton = self.statusBarItem.button {
                statusBarButton.title = "☰"
                statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
                statusBarButton.sendAction(on:  [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])      
            }
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        let statusBarButton=self.statusBarItem.button!

        let event = NSApp.currentEvent!
        event.type == NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp ? print("Right-Click") : print("Left-Click")

        func show(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            self.popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        }
        func hide(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            popover.performClose(sender)
        }
        self.popover.isShown ? hide(sender as AnyObject) : show(sender as AnyObject)
    }
}
```

I can get the popover working, but how would I like to show a different real menu when the button is right-clicked. How do I get this going?